# Is "Ave Dominus Nox" the correct translation for "Hail to the Lord of Night"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin

In the Warhammer 40K universe, the Night Lords (scary stealthy dudes) use the battle cry "Ave Dominus Nox."  This isn't meant to be in Latin, but in High Gothic, a made-up language for the setting which is usually rendered as a sort of twisted Latin.  Presumably, it's supposed to translate to "Hail to the Lord of Night" and refers to the head Night Lord.

My question is: if we speak actual Latin rather than High Gothic, can we do any better?  What's the best way to render "Hail to the Lord of Night" as a Latin battle cry?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The suggestion *ave dominus nox* misses the mark in two ways:
You should be using the vocative case with *ave*, and here *Nox* seems to be a name of a lord rather than the word "night".
I would dismiss that phrasing and look for something else.

The genitive of *nox* is *noctis*, so a literal translation of "lord of the night" would be *dominus noctis*.
But it strikes me as more idiomatic Latin to go with an adjective: *dominus nocturnus* is somewhat literally "nightly lord".
But different things are idiomatic in English and Latin even when both languages have both options, so I think the most apt translation of "lord of the night" is *dominus nocturnus*.

For the greeting you would add *ave* and put the *dominus nocturnus* in the vocative case, when my suggestion for "hail the lord of the night" is ***ave domine nocturne***.
This sentence would be addressed directly to the lord.
If you want to praise him in his absence, perhaps something like "glory to the lord of the night", *gloria domino nocturno*, would work.
The exact use context makes a bigger difference in Latin than English here.

I assumed here that *dominus* is used as a normal noun, not an honorific.
(If you say "Lord Halifax was a lord", the first "lord" is an honorific, essentially a part of the name, and the second one is a a normal noun. The form of the word alone doesn't tell which one it is.)
I also took *nocturnus* here to be a normal adjective, not a name.
Choices on matters like this can have an effect on word order (perhaps *nocturne domine* instead of *domine nocturne*) and word choice.
However, I feel that such differences in nuance are minimal.
Unless you weigh in on the very precise meanings (if any!) intended and what sounds good to your ears, I don't think we can tell what is optimal, but we can certainly improve on the original suggestion.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  I was aware of the declensions, but I'd heard someone else suggest to leave them as they were for more dramatic effect ("he _is_ night, not just the lord of night").  Thanks for the context!

Comment: If you want to say that he is night, it is possible (this is called apposition in Latin) but you will still need to use the vocative *Ave Domine Nox!*

Comment: Of course the master of the doctrine is to be admired, but I think we want the one over the night there too!

Comment: Regarding your latest edit and following up on the discussion in the comments to my own answer to this question. It appears that your edit gets the distinction I point out the other way around. *Dominus* is a honorific in your **original** translation, *domine nocturne* (“Mister/Lord Nightly“ ), and this is exactly what I thought should be corrected. The *nocturne domine* in your latest edit is the grammatically correct translation of OP's request, with *dominus* as a common noun (“Night Master/Lord“). The *honorific* is **preposed,** the *generic noun* is **postponed** – exactly as in English

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian I'm reading *nocturnus* as an adjective, not a name. I imagine that makes a difference. There is room for so many interpretations here.

Comment: What I mean is that when *dominus* is preposed, it functions as a honorific. *nocturnus* ends up being an adjective and a name at the same time, i.e. it's a talking name. That combination reads as “Mister Little”, and in order to get a noun + noun instead of honorific + name, the word order has to be changed. The difference in word order is tied to the difference in lemma in this case (*dominus* the honorific and *dominus* the noun are two different lemmas with two different grammars).

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian Can you cite any of your claims? You keep saying that *dominus* means Mr., but you haven't provided anything to back that up.

Comment: @cmw That *dominus* is a honorific address is well-known to most learnerss and **Joonas** in his edit **makes it perfectly clear** that it's known to him. I therefore find it difficult to understand the nature of your request. I leave it to the doubtful reader to consult any basic dictionary like L&S, Gaffiot, or DMLBS for medieval Latin, all of which an can be found on logeion.com.

Comment: To Joonas: your answer in its present state continues to get the distinction in the word order the wrong way around. If *dominus* is used as a honorific, it should precede the noun, so *domine Nocturne.* Correspondingly, “If the lord in question is a nocturnal one” the translation should rather be *nocturne domine.* Would you mind revising your answer to correct this?

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian It's a simple request. If you can't cite your sources, how do you know you're correct? I checked Lewis and Short before asking this, by the way, and it never says that it functions equivalently to Mr. But the purpose of citing something like this, mind you, as *all* good scholars know, is to establish not only the existence of something, but also show it's development. If this is a later Latin or Medieval development, it undermines your argument completely. In fact, as we have it, both Gaffiot and L&S cite nothing earlier than Seneca. Does it ever appear earlier? Do you know?

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian The late development means that your statement is chronologically unjustified. Would Cato or Cicero have understood *dominus* to mean Mr.? And, if you look carefully, even the Silver Latin citations of L&S do not support your claim. They don't mean "Mr." as we native speakers use it. It wasn't regularly given to every male. It's truly honorific, something that was used with people of importance. That's why it's given to the emperors first. So it's not like *Mr.*, but *Sir*, as Lewis and Short says. But we can only have this type of discussion if you actually do the work.

Comment: @cmw Neither the OP's question nor Joonas' answer is chronologically limited. Likewise, I have made no chronologically unjustified statements. If the chronology interests you, you have the option of opening a question or doing the work yourself. Please notice that this comment thread is not the right place for establishing this, nor to discuss how closely its usage resembles that of En. *Mr.* My exchange with Joonas concerns only the syntax, and  your comments do not seem pertinent to this purpose. I would greatly appreciate it if our discussion with Joonas is permitted without interference

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian I edited my answer a bit, making it more ambivalent to the various options of reading here. It may or may not be optimal. I do not plan to edit it further; I will let this post be and move on. // The comments from cmw are not rude or unrelated interference. I was planning to make very similar remarks, as I felt (like cmw) that you were pushing a too black and white conclusion without clear evidence. I have seen no sources discussing word order and honorifics. Many aspects of the question are related, but I have no interest in discussing any of those aspects any further.

Answer (score 14):

I would like to offer a review of both replies posted so far, and offer a couple of my own suggestions which I think are an improvement on both.

- Laravel's ***Ave Domine Noctis*** is in general fine and correctly expresses the relation between “lord” and “night”. One can imagine *Dominus Noctis* as an official title without much trouble.
- Joonas Ilmavirta's suggestion *ave domine nocturne* is unfortunately less successful – it reads as “Hail Lord/mister Nightly”, where *domine* is a honorific and *nocturne* is an adjective-derived personal name, instead of an adjective modifying the common noun *dominus*.

  - The reason is that *dominus* (from *domus* “house, home”) is ubiquitous as a designation of social status, a title comparable to “Lord” in origin but to “mister” in usage. When used as a title, it's obligatorily placed **before the proper name** (the same limitation applies to *sānctus* “saint”). This usage together with the original word order survives in Spanish and Italian *don,* Portuguese *dom* as honorific titles, which likewise always appear before the name: *Don Giovanni* (*sānctus* also got reduced to *san).* This titular reading is only reinforced by the fact that we have an **address** in the vocative.
- In order to get the intended reading, then, one needs to switch the word order as ***Ave Nocturne Domine.*** Notice that the switch works exactly parallel to the English contrast between Lord Night and Night Lord.

However, the result still doesn't look quite right to me, because it ends up reading like a temporal qualification, as if some Lords are Lords always, but this Lord is nightly-only, a part-time Lord; or more generally, “nightly” somehow qualifies and restricts his Lordship. To express the meaning “Lord of the Night”, Laravel's suggestion works better in our case, even though it's true that in the general case it's the adjective and not the genitive that is often more idiomatic in Latin. Here the adjective's meaning is either too specific or too dervied – it isn't simply equivalent to a noun in the genitive.

---

But I have a suggestion that I think works even better! Latin has a fun little pattern of forming epithets (typically divine) with the meaning “lord, master of X” by compounding X with the participle/adjective *potēns,* “having power over, powerful”. For example [*Ignipotēns*](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/Ignipotens) “(s)he who has mastery over fire” is an epithet of Vulcan. And ours seems to be a perfect opportunity to coin the word *Noctipotēns!* Since we still have a titulary address, adding *Domine* – this time before the name and as a title – is a good idea; besides it looks bad-ass. So in the end we have ***Ave Domine Noctipotēns!*** “Hail [honorific] He-who-has-mastery-over-night”.

But since we're speaking of bad-ass, the best solution may well be to dispense with both the antique-tinged honorific and the mythologically-tinged *-potēns,* and just go for plain old ***AVE [DOMINÁTOR](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/dominator) NOCTIS.*** Can't go more bad-ass than this!

Comment: "Joonas Ilmavirta's suggestion ave domine nocturne is unfortunately less successful – it reads as “Hail Lord/mister Nightly”, where domine is a honorific and nocturne is an adjective-derived personal name, instead of an adjective modifying the common noun dominus." <- This works better than you might think. See Plautus *Amphityo* 1.270.

Comment: @cmw Amphitryo 272 has the personal name *Nocturnus.* I have no issue with using that as a personal name. The issue is with Joonas' placing *dominus* before *nocturnus* which turns the latter into a personal name prefixed with a honorific, when we need *nocturnus* **not** to be a personal name, but an adjective modifying the common noun *dominus.*

Comment: I meant that it works as a name, too. *Domine Nocturne*: Oh Lord Nocturne! This is precisely parallel with *Domine Jesu*. In other words: yes, it would sound like a name, but that could still work.

Comment: @cmw "Hail Lord Nightly" doesn't work as an equivalent of "Hail to the Lord of Night".

Comment: Except proper names are not analyzed etymologically. I'm talking about making Nocturnus the addressee, **not** using it as an adjective.

Comment: @cmw I pointed out that in translating "Lord of Night" Joonas mistakenly ended up with "Lord/Mister Nightly". Most Latin proper names **are** transparent etymologically, they're talking names, originally nicknames. *Caelus Nocturnus* is 100% lexical, Night Sky personified. It's similar to conventionalised divine epithets like *Capitōlīnus, Monēta,* but *nocturnus* is a much more generic adjective and so much less conventionalised; it reads as an ellipsis ”the nocturnal one”. In other contexts it could refer to a nocturnal animal, human, night pot. Tellingly it's a hapax in the classical corpus

Comment: I originally read *dominus* not as a title as a part of a name as in Lord Halifax but as a regular noun. Both readings make sense to me, and I updated my answer to discuss the distinction. I don't think this is quite as black and white as you make it sound, but I do appreciate the reminder on the word order.

Comment: I reply to Joonas' last comment under his own answer.

Answer (score 9):

The words are correct: "dominus" is indeed the Latin word for "Lord" (see for example the New Testament), "nox" is "night", etc.
However, they are not declined so a literal translation of the Latin sentence would be "Hail (the) Lord (the) night".

I would rather suggest to use the vocative case for "Dominus" and the genitive case for "night", that is "Ave Domine noctis".

Answer (score 6):

Laravel's answer I think is best for your precise question, but I note that there's a bit of ambiguity with the people here. You have on the one hand the Night Lords and on the other hand the Lord of the Night, but in Latin their titles would be rendered without distinction.

If you wanted a coherent system in place, the "scary, stealthy dudes" should be *domini noctis* ('lords of the night'), which is the most straightforward way of rendering "night lords." The Romans would have read that as people who have some mastery over the night (cf. *dominos insularum* in Suetonius' *Caesar* 41 or *dominum rerum suarum* in Cicero's *Tusculan Disputation* 3.5.11). I suppose theoretically they could be the night's lords (a subjective genitive), but it doesn't feel natural to me to read it that way.

If they are merely associated with the night, especially if their activities happen at night, *domini nocturni* is an attractive alternative. You have e.g. the *fur nocturnus* ('nocturnal thief') mentioned by Phaedrus and elsewhere.

Yet you also have, found in Plautus, the Nocturnus, "the nocturnal one, i.e. god of the night." He's not really well attested, but fun the passage he seems to be the one in charge of the night.

So if you reserve the title "lord" for both their god and themselves, the distinction is muddied. Moreover, *dominus* as a title or epithet for the gods isn't common before Christianity. You have a few solutions that make their relationships and titles clearer and more classical.

One solution is to keep *dominus* only with mortals (the *domini nocturni* or *domini noctis*), and adopt the title *Rex* for their god. In fact, in Lucan we already have ***Rex Noctis*** as a title for Hades (6.741). If you wanted to go with Nocturnal instead of Hades, you could still do ***Rex Nocturnus***.

Alternatively or additionally, you could also change the Night Lords into something else. If they have a religiosity to them, the *Flamines Nocturni* sounds super cool. To emphasize their fighting prowess, perhaps consider *Bellatores* or *Milites*. If they're in service of him, then *Legati* is an option, or perhaps to emphasize their mastery, *Magistri* could be chosen instead. The latter two have non-military uses, though, so they sound less cool.

One group that might interest you are the *Tresviri Nocturni*:

> The officers here mentioned were called "nocturni Tresviri." It was their province to take up all suspicious characters found abroad during the night. They were attended, probably, by lictors, or subordinate officers, who are here referred to as "homines octo validi," "eight sturdy fellows."

For the imperatives of the above suggestions, the only words you'll need to worry about are the following two, and only in the singular:

- Dominus -> Domine
- Nocturnus -> Nocturne

This is for direct address. Examples (*Ave* or *O* +):

- Rex Nocturne (King Nocturn)
- Domine Nocturne (Lord Nocturn)
- Domine Noctis (Lord of the Night)

But

- Domini Nocturni (Nocturnal Lords)
- Domini Noctis (Lords of the Night)
- Rex Noctis (King of the Night)

---

As an unrelated side note, [Gothic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gothic_language) is not a made up language, but a real one that unfortunately was not well preserved. In language classification, the term "high" refers to geographical location: Old High German was spoken in the south of Germany leading into the Alps; Low German was spoken among the flatlands of northern German.<sup>[1](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Old_English_and_its_Closest_Relatives/3cmkjPaNBvMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=evaluative)</sup>